Lifetime of a sempahore using futex
The futex syscall is commonly used to implement semaphores on Linux. It uses a 32-bit value and we can use the FUTEX_WAIT and FUTEX_WAKE operations to atomically (check the value and go to sleep) and (wake from sleep), respectively.
However, I've encountered a lifetime conundrum if the waiter destroys the semaphore immediately after it returns from wait. Using the POSIX interface for demonstration purposes:
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

void* thread_fun(void* arg)
{
  sem_t* sem = (sem_t*)arg;
  sem_post(sem);
  return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    sem_t sem;
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 0); // initial value == 0

    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_fun, &sem);

    sem_wait(&sem);
    sem_destroy(&sem);

    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}

The trouble is now in the implementations of sem_wait and sem_post, here much simplified:
void sem_post(sem_t* sem)
{
  atomic_fetch_add(&sem->data, +1); // A
  futex_wake(&sem->data); // B
}

void sem_wait(sem_t* sem)
{
  int32_t previous = atomic_fetch_add(&sem->data, -1); // C
  while(previous <= 0)
  {
    futex_wait(&sem->data, previous);
    previous = atomic_load(&sem->data);
    if(previous > 0 && atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&sem->data, &previous, expected + 1))
      break;
  }
}

The sequence of operations could be:

the poster executes A (atomic_fetch_add +1)
the waiter executes C (atomic_fetch_add -1)
the waiter returns and destroys the semaphore
the poster executes B (futex_wake)

The kernel seems to handle it quite benign if you call futex_wake on some unmapped memory, but I wonder what kinds of side-effects you could get with this. For example, if the waiter creates another semaphore at the same location, you could get spurious wake-ups. Or if you place another data structure shared with kernel at that location, I have no idea what the kernel could do.
How is this dealt with in practice?

I wonder if you can leverage the amount of waiters to only call futex_wake if you're somehow guaranteed that there will be a corresponding futex_wait call...

I wonder why this is tagged c and c++. Which are you asking about? For c++, destruction of the semaphore would take the form of a destructor call. And destructors should never be invoked while another external caller is still using the public interface. So this would be a problem for the calling code to solve.

@Wutz It is tagged both because I don't think it matters. In C, you would have something like the sem_destroy function, or flowing off the end of the scope (destroying the local variables). I don't think in C++ there's a special clause for destructors per se, it's probably more of a lemma (because accessing variables during destruction is highly problematic, therefore you should not have another thread accessing members while the destructor is running). One possible solution would be to mandate having semaphores under shared ownership.

For the question "How is this dealt with in practice?" the difference between c and c++ is gigantic. Imagine instead of sem_t you're using a c++ type with a destructor instead of the explicit destroy function. You'll have to jump through some hoops to even recreate your problem scenario. And if you do recreate it the solutions will be different as well.

Obviously you could fix the lifetime problem in this particular case by not calling sem_destroy while there could be other threads calling sem_post, e.g. by calling sem_destroy after pthread_join. As for the kernel, I'm sure it can look after itself and doesn't really care if userspace UBs itself.

@Wutz @.IanAbbott I think a more realistic example might a job object in a job queue. Unless you're using shared ownership, the job object is owned by the one who pushed it and waits for its completion. Completion can be signaled via a semaphore, and the job object subsequently deleted. This will also have the necessary hoops for the problem to appear in a C++ implementation.

There is a similar lifetime issue in the implementation of a joining a thread, unless the kernel provides a way to synchronize on thread exit. Linux does via CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID and pthread_join leverages this (I wonder what it does on other platforms). In promise, libstdc++ uses a shared_ptr to the state shared with the promise, and that state contains the futex. libcxx uses something like an intrusive shared pointer instead (__shared_count).

How one would deal with this in practice in C++ is to ensure the lifetime of the object outlives member function calls.
For example, in C++ the API might look like (using POSIX for the implementation for familiarity, but one could use futex directly):
#include <cassert>
#include <system_error>
#include <semaphore.h>

class semaphore {
public:      
  explicit semaphore(unsigned int initial) {
    if (-1 == sem_init(&sem, 0, initial)) {
      throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category());
    }
  }

  semaphore() noexcept : semaphore(0) {
  }

  // non-copyable
  semaphore(const semaphore&) = delete;
  semaphore(semaphore&&) = delete;
  semaphore& operator=(const semaphore&) = delete;
  semaphore& operator=(semaphore&&) = delete;

  ~semaphore() {
    [[maybe_unused]] int err = sem_destroy(&sem);
    assert(err == 0);
  }

  void post() {
    if (-1 == sem_post(&sem)) {
      throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category());
    }
  }

  void wait() noexcept {
    while (-1 == sem_wait(&sem)) {
      assert(errno == EINTR);
    }
  }

private:
  sem_t sem;
};

And the usage from main with a C++ API would look like:
#include <thread>

int main() {
  auto sem = semaphore();
  auto thread = std::jthread([&] {
    sem.post();
  });
  sem.wait();
}

godbolt
In C++, deterministic destruction automatically causes the correct order: in the main thread, we must sem-wait, thread-join, then sem-destroy. The thread has implied shared ownership of the semaphore object and we cannot and should not destroy it before the thread. But since we create the object before the thread (in order to pass it to the thread), and destruction happens in reverse order, it all just works.
If lexical scoping is insufficient, the usual way to deal with this in C++ would be to make the shared ownership explicit: use a std::shared_ptr<semaphore> instead of semaphore.
Finally, it is notable that C++ does have a standard library std::counting_semaphore already, so one would use that if possible.

Well, ensuring there is no lifetime issue in the first place is certainly a way how this is dealt with in practice... though I still don't understand why now two different people claim that C++ destructors have any influence on the solution :/ Both with manual memory management in C++ and C, you could just mandate that the semaphore must live at least until sem_post() has returned.

The reason for this claim is this is how it's done in C++, meaning this is idiomatic (stdlib has a semaphore, compare it), and the lifetime problem is (a) just not a problem unless you go out of your way and (b) the rules to follow if you do muck with lifetime are consistent with everything else (not specific to this). Yes, you can mandate the ordering of calls and you would in C. I'm answering how one does this in practice in C++.

"I'm answering how one does this in practice in C++" Which is why you got an upvote :) I guess I just see this as multiple steps: the lifetime issue is solved by mandating that destruction of the sem must happen after some external synchronization (which is a bit of a strange requirement for a sync primitive, but at least shared ownership does not turn it into a recursive problem), and you enforce the destruction ordering using nested lifetimes (in your example) and RAII. The semaphore type itself still has the problem, and the solution in the example is the sync via thread join.
